# Facing issue with Firefox browser while running Selenium script

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

**Specs**

Firefox version: 45.0.2
Selenium: selenium-java-2.53.1 (also tried with selenium-java-3.0.0-beta2)

**Code**

```
package Selenium_Practice;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Launch_Browser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\Selenium_Practice\\EXEs\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://abcd.jsp");//just for reference

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='loginForm:user-name']")).sendKeys("admin");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='loginForm:user-password']")).sendKeys("admin");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='loginForm:submit']")).click();

        driver.close();

    }

}
```

**Error**

```
1470892418708 Marionette: Element is missing an accesible name -> id: loginForm:user-name, tagName: INPUT, className: 1470892418759 Marionette: Element does not have a correct accessibility role and may not be manipulated via the accessibility API -> id: loginForm:user-  password, tagName: INPUT, className:
```

After entering user name, password & clicking on 'Submit' button, login form is getting refreshed. Please help in resolving the issue.

Also let me know how to encrypt the password in the code the same can do in QTP.

Comment: Could you share your HTML..

Answer (score 0):

You better use the following:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'user-name')]")).sendKeys("admin");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'user-password')]")).sendKeys("admin");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'submit')]")).click();
```

This is because the character ':' has the special meaning in XPaths.